# MongoDB geospatial $box calculate

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial

I want to use the geoWithin command to return all nearby points within a coordinate. Say I get a random coordinate such as 47.90928383, 53.939493929. I know want to calculate all points within ~1km (of course not exact since it is a box not a circle). The $box requires the bottom left coordinate and the upper right coordinate (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#op._S_box). How would I calculate this based on my input coordinate? Since this is the box command it is done on a Flat surface and not spherical.

I plan on getting the input (cooridnate) and then calculating the upper and lower coordinate using Java.

Comment: It is not that obvious to define what should be a "box" on earth surface. Does its edges follow [great circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) ? And what about a "box" centered on pole ? How would you express its bottom-left vs upper-right coordinates ?

Comment: In addition: _"[...] calculate all points within ~1km"_ Isn't that a _circle_ ?

Comment: I want a box (a perfect square) to be created where the center is the coordinate. I am using this data alongside google map api so my surface type is not spherical but uses the Euclidean plane.

Comment: Calculate all points within a square I would use something like the "radius" of a square. If I need 1 km I could half that and take the distance from the center to a corner squareRoot(0.5)/0.5. Again this does not need to be exactly the same distance in all directions which is why a box works for my use case. In the end though I still need to figure out how to get my upper-left and bottom-right coordinates from my center point.